# Implement TCP Server with two-way communication using Apache Camel Netty using Java DSL where user gets a prompt on connection being established

Tags: java, server, tcp, apache-camel, netty

Looking to develop a TCP Server using "Apache Camel Netty with java DSL" to open a channel where initially TCP Server acknowledges the connection request triggered from the TCP Client by simply sending an acknowledge message such as "Connection Established." followed by "Enter Input:" on the next line. Once the user inputs some text from TCP Client it should be received by the TCP Server, processed and returned back with a response. The same flow shall carry on until the connection and channel is active between TCP Server and TCP Client.

Something on the similar line is available here: https://www.baeldung.com/netty
However, this one is using Java and Netty and does not make use of Apache Camel.

Can anyone please refer to some sample Camel Netty project which can be used to achieve the said requirement.

I searched a lot but somehow not able to get hold of a working Camel Netty solution.
Thanks in advance.